# How can I do manual code-splitting with preact?

Tags: javascript, code-splitting, preact

I want to do code-splitting manually using preact. Preact already splits code for routes, but I want to do it myself.

My use case is that I am building a tool where a user can add widgets to a dashboard. On the home page I only want to include the code for the widgets that the user has configured, not the ones the user has not used.

So I do not want to have the code for all widgets bundled in the bundle.js, but request it lazily when needed, when rendering the list of widgets.

I have attempted to use the `async!` syntax, which I saw in some old commits for the boiler plate, but that did not work.

### A simplified example of my code

#### The configuration data

```
[{ "type": "notes", "title": "Widget 1}, { "type": "todo", "title": "Widget 2"}]
```

#### The render function of the list

```
const Grid = ({ widgets }) => (
    <ul>
        {widgets.map((widget) => <li key={widget.title}><Widget widget={widget} /></li>)}
    </ul>
);
```

## Widget component

Here I have a mapping from type to component:

```
import notes from widgets/notes;
import todo from widgets/todo;

class Widget extends Component {
    widgetMap(widget) {
      if (widget.type === 'notes') {
         return notes;
      }
      if (widget.type === 'todo') {
          return todo;
      }
    }

    render ({ widget }) {
        const widgetComponent = this.widgetMap(map);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{widget.title}</h1>
                <widgetComponent />
            </div>
        );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Preact X, it features `<Suspense>` and `lazy` which is same API React also uses. More about it in depth you can read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Your example, modified would look like this (code adjusted from [here](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/switching-to-preact#suspense-experimental)):

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from `preact/compat`;

const notes = lazy(() => import('./widgets/notes'));
const todo = lazy(() => import('./widgets/todo'));

class Widget extends Component {
    widgetMap(widget) {
      if (widget.type === 'notes') {
         return notes;
      }
      if (widget.type === 'todo') {
          return todo;
      }
    }

    render ({ widget }) {
        const widgetComponent = this.widgetMap(map);
        return (
            <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
                <div>
                    <h1>{widget.title}</h1>
                    <widgetComponent />
                </div>
            </Suspense>
        );
    } 
}
```

---

For older version of Preact, you can put together async loading HOC yourself as long as you have Babel or some other transpiler set up to handle [dynamic module loading](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/)

```
export default asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
  class AsyncComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { component: null };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      const { default: component } = await importComponent();
      this.setState({ component });
    }

    render() {
      const Component = this.state.component;
      return Component ? <Component {...this.props} /> : <div>loading...</div>;
    }
  }

  return AsyncComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example you can use:

```js
import { LocationProvider, Route, Router, lazy } from 'preact-iso';
import NotFound from '../../pages/_404.jsx';
import Header from '../Header.jsx';
import './style.css';

const Home = lazy(() => import('../../pages/Home/index.jsx'));
const Books = lazy(() => import('../../pages/Books/index.jsx'));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <LocationProvider>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Router>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/books' component={Books} />
          <Route default component={NotFound} />
        </Router>
      </main>
    </LocationProvider>
  );
}
```

While the accepted answer uses `lazy` & `suspense` from `preact/compat`, the code above uses `lazy` from `preact-iso`.
At the time of writing this answer, when I initiated a new **preact** project via `npm init preact`, it already used `preact-iso`, so i'm figuring it's their recommended way of using `lazy` these days.

Comment: `lazy` itself it not experimental, no, feel free to use it. The experimental bit is trees that suspend during a patch, as the behavior (even in React) is undefined. As for "initiating a new preact project", you're referring to `create-preact`, while this question was for `preact-cli`. They're different build tools.